# Add extra information to uncaught exception

Tags: java, android, error-reporting

In Google.Play there is a statistic about uncaught exceptions. I would like to know is there any way to add some extra information to exception, so **it will be shown in Google.Play** (cause third party error reporting services can't be used).

I know about `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler` and I suppose I can write something like

```
public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
    throw new CustomException(ex, "extraData");
}
```

with my custom exception message for example.

But are there any other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean?

```
public class CustomException extends Exception
{
    public CustomException(Throwable cause, String message)
    {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, message seems to be the only way to pass an extra information. Main question is how to catch these exceptions

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra). In addition to providing a lot more information than the Google Play crash reports, it also allows you to easily add [custom data](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#wiki-Adding_your_own_variables_content_or_traces_in_crash_reports) to the reports.

Comment: I need to see this information in Google.Play not in other services, even Google Docs

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you are missing the point here. In order to add information to an uncaught exception, you would need to catch the exception. Once you know where and how to catch the exception, the right approach is to handle the exception correctly so that no interruption to the user experience is caused.

Uncaught exceptions occur because you have overlooked an error condition and do not handle an error condition. Handle the error and there will be no uncaught exception to worry about.

Knowing possible error conditions is fundamental to writing well working programs. If you keep on cranking out code oblivious to errors and status codes you will create a mess that will crash on uncaught exceptions often. Handling exceptions and errors takes a lot of time and code but it is simply a part of programming that you can't ignore.

Comment: Point is to have one exception handler which will add extra information for later investigation. This is needed cause I see errors in Google.Play which are not reproduced on test environment, but are present on production (which can be problem with production web services, not the application itself). And I need to find out the reason why these exceptions occur and this is why I need some extra information

Comment: Just put everything you do inside a try { ... } catch (Throwable th) { ... } block then. There is no single place because there are several entry points to your application (onCreate, onResume, onPause, onBackPressed, etc). You have to do it every time your own code is in control. But even that won't solve situations when you pass invalid data to an API and, for example, the UI thread throws an exception.

Comment: I do not want to wrap everything in `try{}catch{}` (because there also background tasks which will need try-catch too). I have wrote about Thread exception handler (or defaultHandler), which can work as a single catch point. My question is will throwing exception in handler help me send extra data to Google.Play. And are there any alternatives.

Comment: per thread handler is much more preferable than per class/section of code etc

Comment: It seems that you have a question that differs from the original. Please create a new question for that.

Comment: my question is in general, with an example