# Android Exception Reporting without Google Play

Tags: android, error-reporting

We offer some apps that only benefit existing customers, so advertising these apps to the world is not worthwhile.

Google Play does not provide an 'unlisted' option. (although you could list it as only available in a 3rd world country, but that is an odd solution) For this and other reasons, we have decided we will not publish the app on Google Play.

In the event of an unexpected stop, we used to request them to send us the system log using one of many available apps. Unfortunately, these logs no longer provide necessary details as they did in older versions of Android. (unless of course you are using a developer USB connection, in which case you get full logs again)

I am thinking the best answer is to use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` to set up my own error reporting service.

What is the recommended way to accomplish error reporting without Google Play? Is there a prominent library that already does this? Would it be better to roll my own, and are there any primary gotchas I need to look out for? Any guidance in this area is appreciated as it might save me from going down the wrong path.

Comment: I [ran across](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14054081/463304) a library called [ACRA](http://www.acra.ch/) which might be what I'm looking for. I will need to use our own server-side rather than a public service (i.e. Google Docs, etc) - looks like that is supported. If there's any other prominent solutions I'm missing please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I obtain crash-data from my Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

I recently found this library to report exception : https://fabric.io

You can also make analytics with it.

Hope it will help